# Unable to install Istio on Kubernetes cluster - permission denied

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I'm trying to install Istio based on the default documentation provided on their website (https://istio.io/docs/setup/getting-started/#download), but I'm running into a permission denied error with a .pem file when I attempt to do so:

```
(base) (username)@ubuntu:~/istio-1.6.0$ istioctl install
This will install the default Istio profile into the cluster. Proceed? (y/N) y
Error: failed to apply manifests: invalid configuration: unable to read certificate-authority /home/(username)/.bluemix/plugins/container-service/clusters/mycluster-br39j0bd02hrl9bffbtg/ca-hou02-mycluster.pem for mycluster/br39j0bd02hrl9bffbtg due to open /home/(username)/.bluemix/plugins/container-service/clusters/mycluster-br39j0bd02hrl9bffbtg/ca-hou02-mycluster.pem: permission denied
```

Any thoughts on how I could resolve this error?

Comment: kubectl against the same cluster works? Have you tried changing the pem files permission?

Comment: kubectl works when I use sudo (e.g. `sudo kubectl get node`, `sudo kubectl get svc,deploy,po --all-namespaces`). How would I be able to modify the permission for the pem files?

Comment: chmod +x filename

Comment: I just ran chmod +x on the pem file, but I'm still getting the permission denied error.

Comment: sudo kubectl anything still works, it's just that istioctl is not recognized as a command when I run `sudo istioctl`...could there be a workaround for this?

Comment: What is your infrastructure? Maybe `sudo chown username:username key.pem` could help? What are the permissions of the pem file ?

Comment: @jt97 Tried running that and still getting the same error. I set `sudo chmod 700` to the pem file and it executed with no errors, but still unable to get istioctl install to execute...

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 running within VMWare Workstation

Comment: Instead of `chmod 700` please try with `sudo chmod 644`. You said kubectl works when you use sudo, what if you apply istio with it, before that, when you download and export istio do it with sudo command.

Comment: I ended up just running the lab on an Ubuntu EC2 instance, and all went smoothly with running the `istioctl` commands...